# How to highlight/mark any element is changed in the data table using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

How to highlight/mark any element is changed in the data table using knockout.
example: jsfiddle.net/hVPLC/

Comment: Please add what you have tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question inspired me to think about this in a data-bound way.

I've posted a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bQfmz/

And the data-binding is this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['watch'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, deprecated, bindingContext) {
        var initial = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            changed = ko.observable(false),
            handle  = null;

        if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
            handle = valueAccessor().subscribe(function (newValue) {
                changed(newValue !== initial);
            });

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                handle.dispose();
            });            
        }

        var watchContext = bindingContext.extend({
            '$initial': initial,
            '$changed': changed
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(watchContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.watch = true;
```

This binding handler creates a new binding context which introduces the values of `$initial`, which is the initial value, and `$changed`, a new observable which is either `true` or `false`.

This can be used in the following manner:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: rows -->
    <tr>
        <!-- ko watch: col1 -->
        <td data-bind="text: col1, css: { changed: $changed }"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko watch: col2 -->
        <td data-bind="text: col2, css: { changed: $changed }"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko watch: col3 -->
        <td data-bind="text: col3, css: { changed: $changed }"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Row(col1, col2, col3) {
    this.col1 = ko.observable(col1);
    this.col2 = ko.observable(col2);
    this.col3 = ko.observable(col3);
}

var model = {
    rows: [
        new Row('a', 'b', 'c'),
        new Row('d', 'e', 'f')
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(model);

// Now change some things.
model.rows[0].col2('x');
model.rows[1].col1('y');
```

CSS:

```
.changed
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Hope this is of use to you.